Problem about a $k$-plane field $E\subset TM$ and an $E$-curve $\gamma(t)$
Let $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $X = \partial_x + y\partial_z,\ Y = \partial_y + x\partial_z$ be two vector fields on $M$. Let $E$ be the 2-plane curve in which $X,Y$ take values. I need to show an $E$-curve $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t))$ that satisfies $z'(t) = x(t)y'(t) + x'(t)y(t)$. I am still battling with definitions for this problem, but if my understanding is correct, I should find a curve $\gamma(t)$ such that $\gamma'(t)\in E_{\gamma(t)} = E\cap T_{\gamma(t)}M$ for all $t$, meaning $\gamma'(t)$ is a linear combination of $X(\gamma(t))$ and $Y(\gamma(t))$? I am not exactly sure if this is what the problem is asking, or even how to solve it if this were the case. Any help is appreciated.

Yes, you are correct. However, your second sentence is incorrect: The word "curve" needs to be deleted; yes, $E$ at each point is spanned by the vectors $X$ and $Y$ at that point.  In fact, you can show more: There is an integral surface through each point that is everywhere tangent to $E$. The exercise you were given gives you a hint that that surface will be $z=xy+c$, with the value of $c$ depending on your location.
